# Initiate a function if and only if a CGPoint is within a view for 2 seconds

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, xcode7

In storyboard I have a `ViewController` called home.

Home has a red `UIView` as a subview and is located at the center of Home.

Red View has a **`LongPressGestureRecognizer`** that when activated the user can move the red view around the screen.

When the User moves the red View close enough to the left of the screen, a `UIView` `Sidebar` pops out.

Within Sidebar are **`n`** uniquely colored `subviews`.

When a user moves red View within the frame of the colored subviews, the colors **`mix`** and the color in the sidebar that red view touched changes colors. It changes into the mix.

`

```
 func handleAuditioneeLongPress(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        switch sender.state {
        case .Began:
            hideSideBar()
        case .Changed:
            let touchPoint = sender.locationInView(self.view)
            thumbnailTrackTouchPoint(touchPoint)
        case .Ended:
            let dropPoint = sender.locationInView(self.view)
            thumbnailWasDropped(dropPoint)
        default:
            break
        }
    }
func thumbnailTrackTouchPoint(touchPoint: CGPoint){
      UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
      UIView.animateWithDuration(0.03, delay: 0.0, options: [.BeginFromCurrentState, .CurveEaseOut], animations: {
                self.red.center.x = touchPoint.x
            self.red.center.y = touchPoint.y - 50
            }, completion: nil)
     if touchPoint.x < 30{
         showSidebar()
         isSidebarOut = true
      }
     if isSidebarOut {
            if touchPoint.x > 135 {
                hideSideBar()
                isSidebarOut = false
            }

            let location = self.view.convertPoint(touchPoint, toView: sidebar)
            let subview = sidebar.hitTest(location, withEvent: nil)
            if( subview != nil) {
            if let coloredIconController = self.sidebarController.viewToColoredIconController[subview!]


/*
if coloredIconController.view.frame.contains(location) for more than 2 seconds mix the colors
*/
```

`
While the user maneuvers the sidebar, I don't want accidental mixing.

So I want a check condition. Red should mix if and only if the touchpoint has been contained within a colored view for 2 seconds.

Comment: In `thumbnailTrackTouchPoint` you could add a save date parameter that occurs only on changed, and if it's outside the limit, it's deleted, either wise set. Then, when ended, you can check is the difference is longer than 2 seconds.

Comment: in method that runs when you enter area fire scheduled timer with method to mix, in method that runs when you get out of that area just invalidate timer, if it is not already a nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initiate a scheduled timer when point enters view

```
myTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2, target: self, selector: "mixing method", userInfo: userInfo, repeats: false)
```

and when cgpoint get out you just

```
if myTimer != nil {
   myTimer.invalidate()
}
```